# Memory leak with a returned string

Tags: c, string, function, valgrind, memory-leaks

I'm writing a function where I manipulate a string and return a string malloc'd after a series of strcpy and strcat:

```
char * doRequest(char *start, char**headers, char *body)
{
  char * reply;
  char * com;
  int i;

  reply = malloc(512 * sizeof(char));
  if (!reply)
    return SRV_ERR;
  strcpy(reply, "Your request ");
  com = strtok(start, " ");

  strcat(reply, com);
  strcat(reply, " with options: ");

  for (i = 0; headers[i] != NULL; i = i + 2)
  {
    strcat(reply, headers[i]);
    strcat(reply, ", ");
  }
  strcat(reply, "has been received.");
  strcat(reply, "\0");
  return reply;
}
```

and then I free the returned pointer in the caller's code:

```
  ...

  char * reply = doRequest(command, headers, body);
  int len = strlen(reply);
  printf("Return message: %s\n", doRequest(command, headers, body));
  if(writen(s, reply, len) != len) printf("Write error while replying\n");
  else printf("Request served correctly.\n");
  free(reply);

  ...
```

I think to correctly free that memory but Valgrind still says that this memory is not freed and is consequently lost. What's wrong with that code??
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `printf("Return message: %s\n", doRequest(command, headers, body));` You call it here also, and don't `free` this memory.

Comment: Also, this code will do un-awesome things the moment you have more than 512 bytes of data come back from doRequest.

Comment: +1 for consulting Valgrind! :-)

Comment: OT: `strlen()` returns `size_t`. And as far as I remember Stevens' `writen()` it does take `size_t` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory allocated by the second call to `doRequest()` is never `free()`d.

I'd propose to replace this line:

```
printf("Return message: %s\n", doRequest(command, headers, body));
```

by this:

```
printf("Return message: '%s'\n", reply);
```

Comment: Sure.. How stupid! I read the code many times and never noticed it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndreaV: You are welcome. Be sure we all know this kind of blindness ... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> printf("Return message: %s\n", doRequest(command, headers, body));

No `free()` for that doRequest call. Did you mean `printf(..., reply)`, maybe?

Also, strcpy + strcat without bounds checking is a sure way to have (exploitable) buffer overflows.